# active SSH session freezes

Tags: ssh

My SSH session to my Ubuntu server (21.10) freezes as I'm actively working on it. Sometimes the connection starts well and one or two minutes in, it just freezes. Then if I close it and open a new one, it just starts frozen. It can also happen that the connection breaks with this message: `Timeout, server xxx not responding.`

All my services on the machine are still running and I can log in using the physical keyboard.

This was not always like this and I'm not sure how to start debugging this. Most questions are about inactive sessions freezing, but this happens as I'm typing commands.

Comment: Hello. In order to offer any help a lot more info is needed. First what version of Ubuntu? What app is being used to make the ssh connection? What are the 2 machines, the one on each end running. What OS? Is there any error message? When did the problem start and what did you do just before it started?

Comment: This sounds like a packet loss problem - I've seen something like this when there's an IP addressing conflict (e.g. a new device added to a LAN with a static IP that conflicts with an already assigned DHCP address)

Comment: @steeldriver this sounds like a good pointer. Doing ssh to itself (localhost) does not hang.

Comment: @David I'm using the latest ubuntu (upgraded from some 21.04 I think) and macs to connect. This was not always like this but has been happening for some time.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version called latest. Ubuntu uses version numbers. There are at least 2 that can be called latest.

Comment: Any packet loss for ping? i.e. `ping -i 0.2 -c 1000 s19` gives `1000 packets transmitted, 1000 received, 0% packet loss, time 203745ms`. Suggest to run tcpdump (or wireshark, if your prefer) on a local terminal watching at the packet level.

Comment: @DougSmythies thanks! Using `tcpdump` I could see that there were a lot of connections from my client computer to another port (different from SSH). It was Plex Media Server doing network discovery. I stopped this and now it seems to be working correctly!

Comment: @DougSmythies Hmmm that might not be it... per se. I reenabled other services in the server and it started freezing again. Could it be something about the number of connections?

Comment: I see you deleted the from internal or external statement. I wonder if you are under attack or resource starved some other way. Some system information, in addition to  what @David asked for might help. Have a look at total connections, `ss -s` . On my WAN and LAN facing server currently 52 (the INET line), but several hundred is not unusual. I don't know if are running iptables, or connection tracking if you are, but then `sudo conntrack -L` might be useful.

Comment: It could also be your client setup too (a combination of both). When I use the native ssh client on ChromeOS, I often get the timeout error. However, if I use Termux ssh client (openssh) on the same computer, the connection is solid and rarely drops, if ever.

Comment: It also may be worth looking into some questions about inactive sessions as the solution may still apply. If it works, it works. If not, then you know it's not the problem/solution.

Comment: Have you checked [your client settings](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) for `ServerAliveInterval`, `TCPKeepAlive`, `ServerAliveCountMax` and others? You can also set these when you run the `ssh` command to connect in order to temporarily test different settings.

Comment: [This sounds very similar to your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084288/keep-ssh-session-alive). The answers cover what settings you can try on the client side to prevent the issue.

Comment: Although, [at least one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37330274) covers what settings you can try on the server side. It may help to increase `ClientAliveCountMax` to a really high number.

Comment: @DougSmythies I deleted that because I could not reproduce it from outside the local network and started doubting myself.

Comment: I had SSH in a different port than 22 and I reverted it back to 22. That, with cutting the connections from Plex Media Server seems to have worked and I was not able to reproduce the issue anymore. So thanks everyone for your suggestions! If the problem arises again I will try these other suggestions.